# zombies inside of docker

Tags: node.js, linux, google-chrome, docker

i have a docker container, which runs node.js application. This application runs a headless-chrome instance.

All work well, but if i kill chrome-instance, and check runned processes list, i will see 2(actually 3 + 2 cat process) zombie chrome process(*defunct*) still in system. I know this processes is a children
(of killed *parent* chrome process), which was not finished correct and attached to *init* process.

I tried to kill it directly - rejected. Also i tried to spawn chrome with `detached:true` flag and again kill all child processes directly, when main chrome receives "exit" signal, anyway `ps -A | grep chrome` shows two *defunct* to me. Any ideas?

**UPD:**
Thanks all for help. Adding `--init` totally solves my issue. Using another base image also works well, but i decided this approach as not neccesary. Also good description of root cause can be found [here](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

larsks pretty much nails the reason, init (or systemd) on linux systems reaps zombie processes when their parent dies. The parent should cleanup its own zombie processes with the `wait` syscall. However, that automatic cleanup does not pass the namespace boundary of a container. So whatever process you run as your entrypoint, and that becomes pid 1, needs to handle these zombies for you.

With recent versions of docker, you can include an init process just by passing `--init` to your `docker run` command. If you are using a version 2.2 compose file, there's an option `init: true` you can define on your service for the same result.

In addition to dumb-init, there is also [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) which is what docker uses under the covers as their own docker-init.

Answer (score 5):

You need a process that will call `wait()` in order to reap any [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).  On a regular system this is handled by `/sbin/init`, but inside a container you will need to provide your own tooling.  If you're developing your own application, consider just calling `wait()` in a loop periodically.

Alternatively, you can consider a container-specific `init` such as [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: do you mean just running a "root@daf1ccd11aaa:~/myapp# **wait**" inside a docker terminal(or call node.js exec('wait', () ={...}))? If yes, it not helped, if i understand wrong - please explain your suggestion

Comment: Read the linked article about zombie processes. You need a PID 1 inside your container that calls the [wait system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). Using something like `dumb-init` (or `supervisord` or other process supervisor) will do that for you.